# <h1> still has an invisible margin after removing margins, padding and line-height?

Tags: css

In the picture you can see that above `name` are `46px` of space and below only `40px` while the `nav` is `100px's` high. I've set `margin: 0;padding:0; and line-height:0;` but it is still there and I can't find anything meaningful via the Chrome Devtools. Why is this happening and how can it be fixed?

[See the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/szoKQ.png)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Document</title>
  <style>
    * {
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
    }
    
    #topper {
      position: relative;
      height: 100px;
      background-color: steelblue;
      color: skyblue;
    }
    
    #name {
      font-size: 30px;
      position: absolute;
      top: 50%;
      transform: translateY(-50%);
      line-height: 0;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <nav id="topper">
    <h1 id="name">name</h1>
  </nav>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: have you checked the spacing of the actual font?  It will have some above and below for characters like t and y plus some natural padding on top of that (which you will see more as the font size grows)

Comment: No and this is my first time seeing this issue, I never had this problem before. I thought it calculates the centering by giving the h1 a point in the middle + or - a pixel if the font is a round number.

Comment: You are using only lower-case letters. Try  "Name" (instead of "name") and you'll see what I mean

Comment: if you `text-transform: uppercase;` it look center.... the lowercase glyphs have more space on the top

Comment: You'll probably get a better answer on https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/ or read this: https://creativemarket.com/blog/whats-the-difference-between-leading-kerning-and-tracking.  By the looks of things most fonts have more space for the ascender than the descender (which is why you have 6 px more on top)

Comment: Thank you all for helping me understand this. I'll be sure to also look deeper into this with the links Pete sent.